# Get all Numbers that are not existing from a Microsoft SQL-VarChar-Column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a Column for ID-Numbers that are not increased in single steps.

So there are Numbers that are not used and this i need. The Column is a VarChar-Column.

For Example:

Used Numbers in the table = 2, 5, 7, 9, 10 etc.

So i need a Query that gives me = 1, 3, 4, 6, 8 etc.

Pseudo-Code something like:

select numbers from Table NOT IN (select numbers from table)!

I have tried with NOT IN and NOT EXISTS, but nothing works.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

EDIT: Range of Numbers is from 0 to 99999999 !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE
(
    Id VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES
 ('1')
,('3')
,('5')
,('7')
,('10')

DECLARE @Range AS TABLE
(
    RangeId VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Range
SELECT TOP (1000000) n = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]))
FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)

select 
    MissingId = RangeId
from 
    @Range AS R
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table AS T ON T.Id = R.RangeId
WHERE
    CONVERT(INT,R.RangeId) <= (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(INT,Id)) FROM @Table)
    AND T.Id IS NULL
order by MissingId
```

Comment: Check the updated answer. You need to apply the necessary conversion on types. Please note joins on a varchar columns are slow compare to INT

Comment: *"Please note joins on a varchar columns are slow compare to INT"* this isn't really true. If the `varchar` is small in length the speed different will be marginal at worst and infinitesimal at best. If you're using a `(n)varchar(MAX)`, however, that's a very different story (but if you're joining on one of those, you probably have a design flaw).

Answer (score 1):

With out using CTE you can use the  master.dbo.spt_values trick. Not sure the actual purpose of this table in msdb, but it contains the values we need. Give it a try. If you have bigger values than spt_values, then divide your max id by spt_value's max, and replace **number+1** with **number+1+(@currentbatch*@maxsptvalues)** (first batch is batch 0). I haven't tested it nor written then code for it, but something of that sort should certainly work. You can do it in a while loop for instance.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tmptbl') IS NOT null
DROP TABLE tmptbl
GO
SELECT * INTO tmptbl 
FROM 
(
SELECT '1' [id]
UNION 
SELECT '3'
UNION 
SELECT '5' ) t


DECLARE @maxid INT = 0
SELECT @maxid = MAX(id) FROM tmptbl

SELECT number+1
FROM master.dbo.spt_values
WHERE number < @maxid
AND Type = 'p'    
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                    FROM dbo.tmptbl
                    WHERE CONVERT(INT,[id]) = (number+1))
ORDER BY number
```

The Result:
2,4

Comment: This is the right Direction. When I do it in my Situation, I get only 100 Numbers. But the Numbers have 8 Digits and there are MUCH more then 100 Numbers!

Comment: Then a rCTe will be *really* slow here, @comidos . YOu can incrase an rCTE to be faster, but if you have 8 digit numbers, you'll want to SQL server to iterative 10 million times. Performance at that stage would be dier (look [here](https://wp.larnu.uk/speed-test-rcte-vs-tally/#single), where I show SQL server was taking a water of a second to generate 25,000 rows. Imagine how long 10,000,000 rows would take!) Both Akash and I show you Set based approaches

Answer (score 1):

As you don't mention what the upper limit is, and recursive Common Table Expressions are [inherently slow](https://wp.larnu.uk/speed-test-rcte-vs-tally/), you would likely be better off with a Tally to achieve this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int);

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID)
VALUES(1),(3),(5),(7),(9),(11),(13),(15),(216); --Big jump on purpose

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.YourTable) --Limit the tally for performance
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3) --1000 rows, add more Ns for more rows
SELECT I AS ID
FROM Tally T
     LEFT JOIN dbo.YourTable YT ON T.I = YT.ID
WHERE YT.ID IS NULL;
```

***Warning***: Based on the comment on another answer:

> This is the right Direction. When I do it in my Situation, I get only 100 Numbers. But the Numbers have 8 Digits and there are MUCH more then 100 Numbers!

*8 digits means you have IDs with a value of 10,000,000 (10 Million) plus. Creating over 10 million rows in a tally will be **very** IO intensive. I strongly suggest putting this into batches.*

*Edit2: Ok, the max (from a comment on this answer) is 99,999,999! This is information that definitely should have been in the question. This process **must** be batched or you will kill your transaction Logs.*

Comment: Thats right the upper Limit is 99999999! In your Case is the Column a Integer. In my Case it is a VarChar. How can I make it running with VarChar-Column?

Comment: Why are you storing numerical values as a `varchar`, @comidos ? But `'1' = 1` is true, so won't be a problem there. You *could* `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value of `I` to a `varchar` if you *must*. I suggest fixing your design though.

Comment: Note my warnings as well now, @comidos . Not telling us this will be 100 Million rows is a ***huge*** over sight. You *need* to batch this. I would suggest 1M row batches.

Comment: Thanks for the Inspiration AND Information! Sorry for not giving the full Info about the Scenario!